# Javascript menu collapses before selection can be made?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, collapsable

I have been attempting to set up this menu so that the submenus will appear when the user hovers over them or clicks them on a mobile device.  Right now, I haven't been able to test the mobile settings, but if you hover over a link containing submenus, the submenu collapses when you attempt to select from the menu.  I'm at a loss.....

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='navbar.css' />
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='menu_jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='navbar.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Widgets</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Location</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  /*COLOR BEHIND MAIN BAR*/
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
    /*NAVIGATION BAR BORDER COLOR*/
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #d8d8d0, white 15%, #d8d8d0 15%, #d8d8d8 15%, white 80%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    max-height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  #cssmenu.expand ul {
    max-height: 900px;
  }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
    /*ACTIVE LINK BACKGROUND COLOR*/
  background: transparent;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    border-right: 0 none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.mobile i {
    float: right;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  border-right: 0 none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
  border-right: 0 none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  /*MENU BAR LINK FONT COLOR*/
  color: #008A8C;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #d8d8d8;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    /*ACTIVE TAB FONT COLOR*/
  color: #000;;
  /*text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;*/
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
  /*DROPDOWN MENU BACKGROUND COLOR*/
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu ul ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
    /*DROPDOWN MENU LINK FONT COLOR*/
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    /*DROPDOWN MENU HOVER LINK COLOR*/
  color: #444444;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu > ul').prepend('<li class="mobile"><a href="#"><span>Menu <i>&#9776;</i></span></a></li>');
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').hover(function(e) {
  $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if( $(this).parent().hasClass('mobile') ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cssmenu').toggleClass('expand');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;   
  }     
});

});
```

Comment: I have put all of that in jsfiddle I assume that is your base?http://jsfiddle.net/VRX7A/

Comment: Oh, ceiling cat, why have you created such cheap-looking free drop-down menu sites? Oh, ceiling cat, the noobs now don't even bother to learn CSS!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a part of js code or css that will handle your menu dropdown being visible while menu child is on hover for desktop version and part of js /css code that will act with on click/on tap for mobile devices as they do not have hover event so you have to make it onclick / ontap. The good example is how to do it is already in Bootstrap [had to documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and see how they accomplished it. [Example navbar.](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)